# Wrapping row names in kableextra with R-Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, word-wrap, kableextra

I want to insert survey questions into a table. The questions are long and run the rest of the table off of the page.

The following code is an exerpt from a Markdown file.

```
{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE,as.is=T}

#Create data set
x<-c(45,2,8,10,32,33)
y<-c(2,3,3,3,3,3)
EDLP_D.1<-cbind(x,y)
colnames(EDLP_D.1)<- c("Sheet", "Please indicate your level of satisfaction with the availability of the instructor outside the classroom. (In selecting your rating, consider the instructor's availability via established office hours, appointments, and opportunities for face-to-face interaction as well and as via telephones, e-mail, fax, and other means") 

#function to compute values needed for table 
vec_fun4 <- function(x,y){
  Vec <-c(colnames(x[,y]),round(mean(x[[y]]),2),length(which(!is.na(x[,y]==F))),length(which(x[,y]==1)),length(which(x[,y]==2)),length(which(x[,y]==3)),length(which(x[,y]==4)))
  return(Vec)   
}

#Switch from long format to wide format
item2.1 <- as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(vec_fun4(EDLP_D.1,1))))

#Make table
library(kableExtra)

kable(item2.1,"latex" ,booktabs=T, align="c",col.names=linebreak(c('Item','Mean','\\textit{N}' ,'Strongly\n Disagree','Disagree','Agree','Strongly\n Agree')),row.names = F,escape=F)
```

I have tried to set row.names=T but it didn't work.have also tried to insert `\n` into the survey item string and that did not work either. Any suggestions to solve the issue of the survey item to wrap within a cell? I am open to using a different package if it solves the problem.

Comment: Your example doesn't quite run for me (maybe you want `colnames(x)[y]` in your function?)  Have you tried `column_spec()` for text wrapping?  Like, e.g., `%>% column_spec(1, width = "20em")`, which I saw [here](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/167).

Comment: That worked!! Thank you!